# Checkout fields - Make billing_address_2 above billing_address_1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

In WooCommerce checkout fields, I'm trying to make billing_address_2 above billing_address_1 on the checkout form.

So instead of it being:

```
Street Address
Apartment
```

I would like to have:

```
Apartment
Street Address
```

Please also note, I'm using the Theme called Avada.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/how-to-reorder-billing-fields-in-woocommerce-checkout-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (related to your comment)…**

Here you have an addition that removes "Address" text label from Address1 field and set it to Address2 field, making also that field (optionally) required and changing a little bit the place holder… I have also another solution (see below after the code).

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_billing_fields_order' );
function custom_billing_fields_order( $fields ) {

    // 1. Customizing address_1 and address_2 fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = ''; // Removing the label from Adress1
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label'] = __('Address', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = true; // Making Address 2 field required
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = __('Apartment, suite, unit etc...', 'woocommerce');

    // 2. Custom ordering the billing fields array (toggling address_1 with address_2)
    $custom_fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name',
        'billing_company',
        'billing_email',      'billing_phone',
        'billing_country',
        'billing_address_2',  'billing_address_1',  ##  <== HERE, changed order
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city'
    );

    foreach($custom_fields_order as $field)
        $new_ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    // Replacing original fields order by the custom one
    $fields['billing'] = $new_ordered_fields;


    // Returning Checkout customized billing fields order
    return $fields;
}
```

Instead of toggling that 2 fields, you could invert the fields placeholders and add make (optionally) required the field Address2, so you will not need to reorder the fields. You can do it this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_billing_fields_placeholders' );
function custom_billing_fields_placeholders( $fields ) {

    // 1. Customizing address_1 and address_2 fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = __('Apartment, suite, unit etc...', 'woocommerce');
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = true; // Making Address 2 field required
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = __('Street address', 'woocommerce');

    // Returning Checkout customized billing fields
    return $fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.

---

Related answers: [Checkout fields: Hiding and showing existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781072/checkout-fields-hiding-and-showing-existing-fields/41788879#41788879)

Official documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: I tried that earlier, that was my first instinct, however this just happens. http://i.imgur.com/XiInJG3.png

Comment: @BarryHanbury I have to make a little update for this… I will let you know when it's ready

Comment: @BarryHanbury I have updated my answer… and it's working as expected…

Comment: When I do this, my state field is gone and the row mark up is messed up.

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1124594/22653626/fcfed43a-ec57-11e6-9be4-e727385493bf.png